# Set language to German in plotly's modebar

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I'm bulding a shiny app using also plotly. Since release  v1.32.0 at Github there is now also a new feature in plotly available to set the modebar into German language:

https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/releases

So I installed the latest version of plotly using `devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly")` and tried to incorporate the new feature with `locale='de'`:

```
# devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly")

library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot"),
  verbatimTextOutput("event")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # renderPlotly() also understands ggplot2 objects!
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~wt)%>%
    config(plot_ly(),displayModeBar = T, collaborate=F, displaylogo=F,locale='de') %>%
      layout(hovermode = 'closest')
  })

  output$event <- renderPrint({
    d <- event_data("plotly_hover")
    if (is.null(d)) "Hover on a point!" else d
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

There is no change at all, the language is still 'en'. What am I doing wrong, can anyone help?

Comment: The minified version of plotly.js used internally only supplies the dictionary for `en` if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. In that case, I wonder how to install the german translation: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/pull/2217 There should be any possibility, otherwise I cannot see the need for the translation. So far, I changed plotly.js by hand, but this seems to be an ugly way...

Comment: **UPDATE** Apparently, it was an issue with the version of plotly. I have now installed the latest version of CRAN and the language setting works as expected.